# JQ Grid: Checkbox not posting value while adding or editing Record

Tags: jqgrid

I am using customized check box [icheck](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/)  in JQ Grid edit and add form but checkbox element  is not getting posted to the server even it is checked.

Here is the generated markup for the form:

```
`<td class="CaptionTD">
    Status
</td>
<td class="DataTD">
    &nbsp;
    <div style="position: relative;" id="userGroupBean.isActive_icheck" class="icheckbox_square-green checked">
        <input title="" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;" class="FormElement" role="checkbox" name="userGroupBean.isActive" id="userGroupBean.isActive" offval="0" value="1" checked="" type="checkbox">
        <ins style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255) none repeat scroll 0% 0%; border: 0px none; opacity: 0;" class="iCheck-helper"></ins>
    </div>
</td>`
```

Comment: @Oleg Please look into it.

Comment: HTML markup is not enough for understanding the problem. You wrote that you used icheck in jqGrid. Which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or some old jqGrid in version <=4.7)? How you use icheck? It's better that you post small demo (JSFiddle demo for example), which demonstrates the problem.